# In a discrete metric space $X$ no proper subset of $X$ can be dense in $X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

While reading a book on Introductory Functional analysis, I saw the statement that,

> In a discrete metric space $X$ no proper subset of $X$ can be dense
> in $X$

*So i thought to prove it. But before going to prove it, i was thinking to verify this statement first!*

**Verification of statement**: So i consider the set $X=[0,5]$ equipped with discrete metric. Let $Y=(0,5)$ clearly $Y$ is proper subset of $X$. So according to above statement, $Y$ can't be dense in $X$. So that, we must have $\bar Y≠X$, where $\bar Y$ denotes closure of $Y$ in $X$. So i think we need to show there exists some point $a\in X$ which is neither a point of $Y$ nor a limit point of $Y$.(**Am, I correct?**) I claimed that, such a point is $0\in X$. Because, $0\not\in Y$ and there exists a neighborhood $B(0,1/2)=\{x\in X: d(x,0)<1/2\}=\{0\}$
Such that, $B(0,1/2)$ contains no points of $Y$ different from $0$ itself. Hence $0$ can't be limit point of $Y$ (**Am i correct**?)
Hence, we have $\bar Y≠X$ and so that, $Y$ is not dense in $X$.

**Is my verification is correct?**

**Proof of statement** let $Y$ be any proper subset of $X$. Then to show $Y$ is not dense in $X$, that is, to show $\bar Y≠X$. Let $a\in X$ such that, $a\not\in Y$. Then, it is sufficient to show that, $a$ is not a limit point of $Y$. Consider a neighborhood $B(a,1/2)=\{x\in X: d(x,a)<1/2\}=\{a\}$ thus there exists a neighborhood of $a$ which contains no point of $Y$ other than $a$ itself. Hence $a$ can't be a limit point of $Y$. Hence $\bar Y≠X$. As required.

**Is my proof is correct?**

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sir , and 0XLR sir, thank you so much for verification of solution.

Comment: It is correct but it is easier to note that in any topological space $X$ and any $Y\subset X,$ we have $\overline Y=X$ iff $Y\cap U\ne\emptyset$ whenever $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $X$. So if $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is dense in $X$ then $Y$ must intersect $\{p\}$ for every $p\in X,$  i.e. every $p\in X$ must belong to $Y$.... In general, in any space $X$, if $Y\subset X$ and if $U$ is an $open$ subset of $X$ then $Y\cap U\ne\emptyset \iff \overline  Y\cap U\ne\emptyset.  $

Comment: A easy way might be too note that in a discrete topology each set is both open and closed by the topology. Therefore a proper subset by nature is closed and hence by ness cannot contain all elements of the bigger set. Hence it cannot be dense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. But there is another way to look at it too: If $X$ is discrete, then if $Y$ is a proper subset, $X\setminus Y$ is open (as all subsets are open in a discrete space!) so $Y$, its complement, is closed. So $\overline{Y}=Y \neq X$ is $Y$ is not dense.